# How to keep only a part of an explode of a csv column in php?

Tags: php, csv, explode

I have this php code that allows me to read a csv file and add 10 columns at the end to decompose the column $data[23].

This column contains for example :

```
M6-Min Ord Qty 6,GO-Good Support,RP-Removable Padding
M6-Min Ord Qty 6
M6
```

I would like these lines there:

```
PICT01 PICT02 PICT03 PICT04 PICT05
M6      GO     RP
M6
M6
```

I would like to display and keep only the part to the left of the dash. For the moment my code works but just separates this information on all the columns, how can I have only the part to the left of the dash?

```
<?php
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

            $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
            $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
            return  $launch;
        }

//Modifications on csv file
$delimiter = ";"; 
$csv_data = array();
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
        
        //Add columns at the end
        $data['Pictures Names'] = (!empty($data[4]) ? ($data[7] ?: '') . "_" . $data[4] . '.jpg' : ''); 
        
        
        $exploded = multiexplode(array(",","-"),$data[23]);
        
        $data['PICT01'] = $exploded[0];
        $data['PICT02'] = $exploded[1];  
        $data['PICT03'] = $exploded[2];  
        $data['PICT04'] = $exploded[3];  
        $data['PICT05'] = $data[23];  
        $data['PICT06'] = $data[23];  
        $data['PICT07'] = $data[23];  
        $data['PICT08'] = $data[23];  
        $data['PICT09'] = $data[23];  
        $data['PICT010'] = $data[23];  


        //Modifications on the fourth line
        if ($row == 4) 
        {
               //All uppercase
               $data = array_map('strtoupper', $data);  
               $data = str_replace(' *', '', $data);
               $data = str_replace('/', '', $data);                             
        }       
            $csv_data[] = $data; 
                              
        $row++;      
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Split the string by comma and then by dash

Comment: Do I have to make two explose on the column? But how do I keep the left part of the dash? @ADyson

Comment: The problem with your `multiexplode` is that you cannot know which of the elements was exploded by comma and which by dash. Do two explodes, first by comma to separate entries and then iterate them and do a second explode by dash. That way you'll know that the first element is the one before the dash.

Comment: Two explodes would make sense. Well, 3 actually. One explode on comma, then two on dashes. The bit to the left of the dash would be the first items in each of the arrays returned by the last two explodes.

Comment: I do something like this `$exploded = explode(",", $data [23]);
$exploded2 = explode("-", $exploded);`
 or with a foreach for the second one ?

Comment: Yeah that's a good start. Try it and see

Comment: It doesn't work, my mistake "Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in..."

Comment: You can't pass the whole array in, no. You need to pass in one of the results of the first explode at a time. Hence the need for two explodes on the dash

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: The first explode (by comma) should return an array containing 2 items. Now you need to explode each of those items individually, by dash.

Comment: So I tried with $explosed[1] for the explose '-' but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what "$explosed" is. That doesn't feature in your earlier code. And for future reference "doesn't work" is no use as a description of a problem, it says nothing about what actually happened, so no-one can help you on that basis. Anyway I can see you're still confused, so I added an answer below to explain it fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process a single row, you need to first split the string by comma. Then you need to take each result of that split separately, and split it by dash. Finally, add the first item from each of those dash splits to your output - they will be the strings you are looking for.

e.g. here's a function which would split a single row as per your sample data:

```
function multiSplit($string)
{
    $output = array();
    $cols = explode(",", $string);

    foreach ($cols as $col)
    {
        $dashcols = explode("-", $col);
        $output[] = $dashcols[0];
    }
    
    return $output;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
$row = "M6-Min Ord Qty 6,GO-Good Support,RP-Removable Padding";
$out = multiSplit($row);
var_dump($out);
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1b7b60da02b9ef13c5747414016aa0fcf296249

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanations. Now I understand how it works! But I have a problem, with an English Excel that has comma separators like csv it doesn't work but with an Excel that has ";" as a separator yes

Comment: Then you need to change the explode command to use ;. Or if you want it configurable then make a variable to pass in the delimiter to the function, like in your original code